# Persist data in local storage google app engine with Junit + eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, junit, objectify

My setup:

win 7 , eclipse , GAE sdk 1.8.5 ,objectify 4 , junit4

I am trying to write Junit test cases to save two Car entities and retrieve them. I am using objectify for it and it works just fine.

My problem is that I need to persist those entities across my many runs of the test cases, that means once I save using doSaveCar() in one run , in the next run  , I should get back those two entities when I run doListCar(). How do I **persist local storage across my various junit test runs in eclipse** environment ?

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;


import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalMemcacheServiceTestConfig;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalServiceTestHelper;

public class OFYTest  {

    private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(
            new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig(),
            new LocalMemcacheServiceTestConfig());

        @Before
        public void setUp() {
            helper.setUp();

        }
        @After
        public void tearDown() {
            helper.tearDown();
        }

        @Test
        public void doSaveCar() {

            new CRUDServiceImpl().save(new Car("Mustang", "green"));
            new CRUDServiceImpl().save(new Car("SRT", "red"));

        }


        @Test
        public void doListCars(){

            new CRUDServiceImpl().list(AbstractEntity.class);


        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I keep the data from one run to the other with using objectify, junit, mockito and google-app-engine, by setting the `NoStorage`flag.

```
dsService.setNoStorage(false);
```

Refer to the below junit test

```
private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
          new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalUserServiceTestConfig())
              .setEnvIsLoggedIn(true)
              .setEnvAuthDomain("localhost")
              .setEnvEmail("test@localhost");

  @Before
  public void setupCustomerServlet() {
    helper.setUp();
    LocalDatastoreService dsService = (LocalDatastoreService)helper.getLocalService(LocalDatastoreService.PACKAGE);
    dsService.setNoStorage(false);
    customerServlet = new CustomerServlet();
  }

  @After
  public void tearDownHelper() {
    helper.tearDown();
  }

  @Test
  public void testDoGet() throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);

    // A test entry
    Customer customerIn = new Customer();
    customerIn.setName("Felix");
    customerIn.setAddress("Kuestahler");
    String json = (new Gson()).toJson(customerIn);

    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

    when(request.getReader()).thenReturn(new BufferedReader(new StringReader(json)));
    when(response.getWriter()).thenReturn(new PrintWriter(stringWriter));

    customerServlet.doPost(request, response);

    Customer customerOut =  (new Gson()).fromJson(stringWriter.toString(), Customer.class);

    assertEquals(customerOut.getName(), customerIn.getName());
    assertEquals(customerOut.get_id() > 0,true);

    stringWriter = new StringWriter();

    when(request.getReader()).thenReturn(new BufferedReader(new StringReader("")));
    when(response.getWriter()).thenReturn(new PrintWriter(stringWriter));

    customerServlet.doGet(request, response);

    System.out.println("Out: "+stringWriter.toString());

  }
```

My list of locally stored customers is growing after each mvn test run.

```
imac:~ Felix$ ls -l /Users/Felix/Development/workspace-clb/clb-appEngine/./WEB-  INF/appengine-generated/
total 32
-rw-r--r--  1 Felix  Felix     81 22 Okt 22:00 datastore-indexes-auto.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 Felix  Felix  10068 22 Okt 22:00 local_db.bin
imac:~ Felix$ ls -l /Users/Felix/Development/workspace-clb/clb-appEngine/./WEB-INF/appengine-generated/
total 32
-rw-r--r--  1 Felix  Felix     81 22 Okt 22:08 datastore-indexes-auto.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 Felix  Felix  11265 22 Okt 22:08 local_db.bin`
```